# Keeping table formatting in Sage with multiple tables

Tags: formatting, sage

As the title suggests, I am trying to keep proper table formatting in Sage while displaying multiple tables (this is strictly a formatting question, so no knowledge of the math involved is necessary). Currently, I am using the following code:

```
my_table2 = table([column1, column2], frame = True)
my_table1 = table([in_the_cone, lengths_in_cone], frame = True)
result_table1 = my_table1.transpose()
result_table2 = my_table2.transpose()
result_table1
result_table2
```

With this, I receive no output for table1 and the following output for table2:

[image]

I want both tables to look this way, but having no output for the first table is no good. So I tried changing the bottom two lines to:

```
result_table1, result_table2
```

While this does display both tables, the formatting now looks like:

[image]

Is there a way I can display both tables at the same time with the first formatting?

Answer (score 0):

It would have been nice for you to include a full minimal working example, but in any case it does depend a little on the output.

Basically, in a notebook or other "cell", only the last return value prints to the screen in some fashion (sometimes via a "hook" as in your case).  But if you use the comma, that implicitly creates a "tuple" which is then printed as a tuple, so you lose that "hook" to display things with math modes (since a tuple doesn't have that).

In this case, the (newish) canonical way to achieve what you want is

```
pretty_print(result_table1)
pretty_print(result_table2)
```

though you may want to put `print "\n"` in between so they don't end up right on top of each other.

Edit: Here is a picture in Jupyter inside of Sage.

[image]

Comment: I am currently using Jupyter and that doesn't seem to compile. Do I need to import a library? Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: You need to be using Jupyter in Sage itself, presumably.